# Firebase add map with unique id to document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a map to a firestore document using JS. The below code is working, but I want to replace the "dataString" in the map with the actual date. review the attached image please

```
        dateString = "24/02/2023"

        let dayStatusDetails =  { dateString : {
            status: day_status,
            date:   status_date,
            note:   day_note
        }}

        await createDayStatus(doc_id, dayStatusDetails)
```

- The question has been answered, but I've added the create function below for those who may ask in the future.

  ```
  export const createDayStatus = (id, dayStatusDetails) => {
      return dailyStatusCollection.doc(id).set(dayStatusDetails ,{ merge: true })
  }
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```js
const dateString = '24/02/2023';

const dayStatusDetails = {};
dayStatusDetails[dateString] = {
     status: day_status,
     date: status_date,
     note: day_note
};
```